Hibernate not see @ManyToOne annotaion
i have two entites
    @Entity
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Table(schema = "repos", name = "tickets")
    public class TicketEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = TicketTableEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_table_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private TicketTableEntity ticketTable;
    ...

and second:
    @Entity
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Table(schema = "repos", name = "ticket_tables")
    public class TicketTableEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "repo_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private RepositoryEntity repository;
    private boolean onlyOwner;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticketTable", targetEntity = TicketEntity.class)
    private List<TicketEntity> ticketEntityList;`
    ...

the problem is i getting error:
Association 'com.example.repository.model.RepositoryEntity.ticketTable' is 'mappedBy' a property named 'ticketEntityList' of the target entity type 'com.example.ticket.model.TicketTableEntity' which is not a '@OneToOne' or '@ManyToOne' association
for me it's seems like hibernate cannot find @ManyToOne annotation in TicketEntity class but annotaion is already there.
i using spring boot 3.2.5 if it have any matter
i trying remove @ManyToOne annotation to check if ai getting diffrent error, but it's still same. Also trying change property names, removing and adding targetEntity in annotations.`

The error comes from the RepositoryEntity class. Please show it.
